# I want to set animation on ImageView

Tags: android

i want to make a toss app ..it is spining all time and will not stop to show a head or tail..i want that when i click on the coin then it should spin for 2 3 seconds and then stops to show head or tail at random selection...but it is continuously spinning.
Here is the code...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView Coin;
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Coin=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgViewcoin);
    Coin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
            animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            animation.setDuration(3000);
            Coin.startAnimation(animation);
            animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    final int[] photos = {R.drawable.heads, R.drawable.tails};
                    final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgViewcoin);
                    final Random ran = new Random();
                    int i = ran.nextInt(photos.length);
                    image.setImageResource(photos[i]);
                    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                 public void onClick(View v) {
                                                     int k = ran.nextInt(photos.length);
                                                     image.setImageResource(photos[k]);
                                                 }
                                             }
                    );
                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                }
            });
            Coin.startAnimation(animation);
         }
      });
  }
  }
```

Comment: Call `coin.clearanimation` in the imageview `OnCickListener`

Comment: when you get onAnimcationEnd clear animation in that call back.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the findviewbyid from onclick and use with Coin instance you have.